# Stack error in my c++ code, what is it and how to fix it?

Tags: c++, stack

Glad to be a member of this coummunity finally! This question is a stupid one, I guess, and similar questions are answered; I checked them, but none of them helped me. I can't find the error and I can't fix it because I don't understand it. I'm in high school and a C++ beginner. Today, we had a competition in C++ and because of this error I got 0 for the whole task.
First part of the task was to enter n string a (without spaces) and then to generate string n1. N1 members are all characters from n that have an ASCII value between 100-110.
This is how I did it:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string n;
    string n1;
    cin >> n;

    int l;

    //here i get the length of n to use in for
    l=n.length();

    //i change all chars to . so i can do an output more easily later
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
        n1[i]='.';
    }

    int a;
    for(int i=0; i<l ;i++){
        //ascii of n[i]
        a=n[i];
        if(a>99 && a<111){
            n1[i]=n[i];
        }
    }


    for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
        if(n1[i]!='.'){
            cout << n1[i] << endl;
        }
    }

return 0;
}
```

We worked in Visual Studio, it crashed and showed something that I really don't understand... something about some restrictions. I don't work in VS, I'm running Linux so i work in codeblocks, I thought that the problem was in VS. I checked on my home computer and it showed me this error.
When string length is below 25, everything works fine.

What exactly is this error(or maybe a warning) and how to fix it. I found somewhere that this can be disabled in ide, but i guess that's just a way to avoid the problem.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: stack smashing detected after 25+ long string is entered

Comment: n1 string is empty, so when your for loop tries to set l characters to ‘.’ It will be overwriting something it should not.

Comment: but by that logic, even if i don't do that with for loop, after i put something in n1[1] for example, i overwrited something that should not be overwrited?

Comment: Yes. `n1[i]` exhibits undefined behavior, on the very first iteration of the very first loop. Replace it with `n1.assign(l, '.');`

Comment: @whomanx -- *I thought that the problem was in VS* -- A compiler that is used by thousands of programmers, and possibly hundreds if not thousands of companies isn't going to get things wrong with simplistic code such as the one you posted.  If you run your program, and the program doesn't work correctly when built with another compiler, assuming your program has bugs.  You had a hidden bug that wasn't detected when you ran using `g++` (the actual compiler that CodeBlocks uses).

Comment: This is working now, but i still don't get it. What is difference between those two n1.assign(l, '.'); and  n1[i]='.';

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie but codeblocks told me about a bug, while VS just crashed. I'm not used to VS, not saying it's bad...

Comment: @whomanx -- Instead of `n1[i] = '.';`, try `n1.at(i) = '.';`  You will see you get a `std::out_of_range` exception thrown, regardless of the compiler.  The `at()` function does bounds-checking.

Comment: why does changing chars to `.` make output easier?

Comment: @whomanx Also, I just ran the program in Visual Studio in debug mode.  You clearly get a "string subscript out of range", so I don't know what you're claiming when you say Visual Studio did not detect the error.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i see. Thanks. I'm not sure, i don't really know how to set up vs corectlly, in my case, it just crash.

Comment: @whomanx -- This has nothing to do with setting up Visual Studio correctly.  Your program has a bug that introduces *undefined behavior*.  That behavior can be anything -- working all the time, working none of the time, work at certain times of the day, work when compiled with one set of compiler options and fail when compiled with another set of options, etc.

Comment: @NonCreature0714 i change all chars to '.' so later when i input those chars that have ascii 100-110 into the string, i can do output with if(n1[i] != '.'). That's an idea, im sure there are better ways, but thats how i done it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie then there was something wrong with environment, i really can't tell what was the problem, but i at least know what was causing that error.

Comment: @whomanx You probably were running a release version under Visual Studio, not a debug version that checks for these things.  But even so, I stated that using `at()` would have given you an exception, regardless of the compiler used.

Comment: Yes. Thank you all!